# Oracle - join optionally based on a value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two Tables:

1) Employee Table

```
Name    ID     City
John    1      New York
Tom     2      Vancouver
Ash     3      
Chris   4      Oakland
```

(Please note that missing city information for Ash)

2) City Table

```
Name       Category
New York   Type-1
Vancouver  Type-2
Oakland    Type-1
```

I would like to do a query which will print all employee names and optionally the city type, if available.

The expected output in the above case is

```
Name           Type
John          Type-1
Tom           Type-2
Ash           
Chris         Type-1
```

I tried,

```
SELECT e.Name
       c.Type
FROM employee e, city c
WHERE e.City = c.Name
```

with no luck.

PS: I am new to Oracle and SQL

Comment: Here is some info on how to format your questions for readability: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Learn more about `JOIN` clause, especially `LEFT JOIN` one:
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/joins.php

Answer (score 0):

You need Left Join:

```
SELECT e.Name c.Type FROM employee e
Left join city c  on e.city=e.city
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT e.Name, c.Type
  FROM employee e
  LEFT JOIN city c ON e.City = c.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how this is tagged Oracle, I want to input the option of using Oracle SQL rather than ANSI:

select e.name, c.type
  from employee e, city c
 where e.city = c.city(+)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need understand how SQL joins works. Read this ilustrated post below to understand what you need.

https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/